# Верстка двух горизонтальных линий с текстом между ними

Tags: css, css3

Всем привет! Учусь вёрстке. Нашел макетик для тренировки и в нём есть такой вот Title с 2-мя горизонтальными линиями слева и справа. Возможно ли средствами html + css сверстать такое? Или идти в сторону использования SVG? Подскажите или поделитесь ресурсами, где можно почитать об верстке таких элементов :)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный макет разумеется можно точь-в-точь сверстать, но в это мало практической ценности, если данные линии не являются границами каких-то блоков. Если вам нужны просто две линии по бокам текста, то можно разобрать данный код и настроить под себя:

```css
.txt {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.txt::before {
  content: '';
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
.txt::after {
  content: '';
  left: 38px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="txt">Text</h1>
```

Если данные линии просто фоновый декор как на вот этом примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То проще использовать другие способы, например: фоновые изображения, спрайты и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. по-хорошему мне лучше экспортировать эту линию из макета и вставить как картинку? Тогда получается другой вопрос: а как можно расположить текст так чтобы при изменении разрешения он не уезжал из области, в которой находится (между двумя линиями посередине)? У меня просто на макете есть 3 места, где используются такие элементы и всех разное текстовое наполнение и искривление этих линий.

Comment: @alexander, если у вас при изменении разрешения все ломается, то используйте в качестве размера текста rem, em, а для изображения настройку в процентном соотношении. Если у вас ломается при изменении наполнения текста, то используйте абсолютное позиционирование изображения относительно текста